# What FPGA vendor boards are supported (well) by Chisel?

Tags: fpga, chisel

What FPGA vendor boards are supported (well) by Chisel? Are most FPGAs on the market generically supported? Or do we need to be careful about some details when buying? If so, what should we pay attention to?

I really need a hardware suite that minimizes the gap and hassles between the simulation and the actual synthesis layer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chisel produces a synthesizable subset of Verilog 2001 that is supported by all FPGAs and FPGA tool vendors.

By example, you can write Chisel code for an inverter and use this to generate Verilog:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage

class Inverter extends RawModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val out = IO(Output(Bool()))
  
  out := !in
}

(new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new Inverter)
```

The produced Verilog is shown here:

```
module Inverter(
  input   in,
  output  out
);
  assign out = ~in; // @[main.scala 10:10]
endmodule
```

This Verilog file can then be used in any FPGA toolchain (open or closed source) that supports Verilog. You would need to write the associated collateral that the toolchain wants (implementation constraints file, etc.). Functional verification can be done a lot of ways, e.g., writing Verilog/SystemVerilog testbenches for the generated Verilog, using [cocotb](https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/) for Python-based testbenches, or using one of the Chisel testing libraries (which actually run tests on the Verilog) like [ChiselTest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2). ChiselTest actually uses Verilator as one of its possible backends meaning that the tests you write in ChiselTest will run on a Verilator-compiled binary. This is a concrete example of tight coupling between generated Verilog and a tool that only ingests Verilog.

Note: this views FPGA vendor tools as "Verilog to bitstream compilers" and not as "integrated development environments". By this view, FPGA vendor tools support any of the HDLs of a similar type including, but not limited to: [Clash](https://clash-lang.org/), [nmigen](https://m-labs.hk/gateware/nmigen/), and [SpinalHDL](https://spinalhdl.github.io/SpinalDoc-RTD/). For IDE-support, a Java IDE is going to be better for doing actual Chisel development, e.g., Emacs with Scala metals or IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: I guess we have a different view on the "well supported", you see any language that generate any king of verilog as "well" supported.

Comment: Good observation. I interpreted the body of the question as clarifying this: "Are most FPGAs on the market generically supported? Or do we need to be careful about some details when buying? If so, what should we pay attention to?" HDL language choice (whatever the HDL is) shouldn't affect this, so long as you have a compiler that produces the language the FPGA tools accept.

Answer (score 0):

Chisel is not supported natively by any vendor tool that I know. The FPGA could be programed by open source compilers which could support natively chisel (I didn't find any, but that doesn't there is none).

Now it would still work well for FPGA design, the [compiler](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl) will generate verilog that all the FPGA vendor tool supports.
In that case, as you can see you are far from minimizing the gap between the simu and synthesis! But using chisel over low-level RTL language offers advantages that might overcome those differences in a lot of cases.

Since you are asking this question I am guessing that you don't have a lot of experience in FPGA. I would advice, to pick the same board as an open source project that uses chisel. This approach is true for any language you end-up picking (chisel or not), pick an open source of that language and take the same platform.

from the doc: https://www.chisel-lang.org/
" Chisel adds hardware construction primitives to the Scala programming language, providing designers with the power of a modern programming language to write complex, parameterizable circuit generators that produce synthesizable Verilog."

### major FPGA vendor tools:

[Xilinx's vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) => check page 7, supports: VHDL, verilog, system verilog

[Intel's quartus](https://www.intel.la/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug-qpp-compiler.pdf) => page 54, supports: VHDL, verilog, system verilog

[Mentors's questa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ModelSim) => supports VHDL, Verilog, SystemVerilog, PSL, SystemC

### open source compiler/ simulator:

[Verilator](https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator) supports: verilog, system verilog

[yosys](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys) supports:  Verilog-2005

Comment: Thanks. This I understand. I am asking because I am worried about some potential hidden intricacies.

Comment: and you should! Chisel is not really used a lot, so you will in your own. having a big gap between simu and synthesis will cause a ton of problem not only on correctness of the design, but also on timing fixes. where the code used for the FPGA is not the one you created but auto generated based on what you wrote.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrectly asserting two opposite things: (1) No FPGA vendor tools support Chisel and (2) all FPGA vendors support Chisel because they support Verilog. The latter is what matters. In support of (2), consider an open source POWER microprocessor built using Chisel that uses an entirely open source FPGA toolchain: https://github.com/antonblanchard/chiselwatt.

Comment: none of the vendor tools are able to use chisel. Now you could think that supporting verilog, which could be generated by any language on earth (including chisel) means that chisel is supported. In that case, all language are supported, R, python, pascal, java, C++...
Or, we can simply says, verilog is supported, meaning that chisel is not.

Comment: the project you gave uses verilator to simulate (which uses the generated verilog) and https://github.com/YosysHQ/nextpnr for place/route, which also uses the generated verilog.
which is a good example to show that chisel is not supported, but the generated code by chisel is supported.

Comment: To be similarly pedantic about what it means to "support" a language--No FPGA toolchain supports Verilog, they support some synthesizable subset of Verilog when combined with an appropriate amount of configuration and wrapping of the interfaces. Vanilla Verilog doesn't work on FPGAs either--you generally need a flow to make it work. The question asker is right to be concerned about the flow but that's generally true of Verilog and Verilog designs as well. Arbitrary Verilog projects don't work on every (or even necessarily any) FPGA vendor.

Comment: @JackKoenig you are right to be precise. I am assuming that we are also talking about the synthesizable part of chisel, as syntheisable part of verilog, systemVerilog, VHDL...

Unless, you insiste I would like to avoid to add "synthesizable" every time I reference a language in the answer (chisel, as others)

Comment: My point isn't that anyone should add "synthesizable" before referencing a language, it's that we generally accept simplifications in speech for clarity. Obviously when someone talks about FPGA support for Verilog, they implicitly mean synthesizable. I'm making the same argument about "supports". Just because the tool itself won't read the Chisel, doesn't mean there's all that much friction to using Chisel designs on FPGAs. It's one extra step, run the generator. In a normal shell-based flow the friction is very small; in the GUI, sure, you have to run an extra command.

Comment: In fact, an advantage of Chisel over Verilog is that we generate dead simple Verilog which makes it maximally compatible with tools (this is an explicit goal). Thus considerations about tooling support are often _smaller_ because any Chisel will work on any FGPA, you don't have to avoid specific constructs. Chisel exists because the original devs were trying to use SystemVerilog on Xilinx FPGAs and ran into so many bugs, unsupported features, and inconsistencies with simulation that they decided there needs to be a better way.

Comment: I think that you are going into "is it a good tech/language". I am not asserting any of that sort.
The question is fairly simple, is it supported?
I listed a list of common tools, used for FPGA dev, chisel is not listed.

Comment: My disagreement is over the statement "Chisel is not supported **at all** by any vendor tool that I know" (emphasis mine). Your second and third paragraphs are a lot better and get more into the subtlety here. Especially looking at the 3rd paragraph, I would recommend the same thing for someone new to FPGAs with a Verilog project.

Comment: then let's change to  "Chisel is not supported natively by any vendor tool that I know"

I agree with the 3rd paragraph, I will emphasise what you are saying